# Jenkins - Get FreeStyleProject parameters using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How do I get a FreeStyleProject parameters using groovy and Jenkins script?

I know how to get the job name:

```
for (item in Jenkins.instance.items) 
{
    if (item.name.startsWith('NAME')) 
    {
      println("name:" + item.name) //Job name
    }
}
```

Each job has serveral parameters: A choice parameter ("A") and String parameter ("B"). 
I'd like to access all jobs in jenkins that starts with a specific name and change their parameters values.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do, you want to access jobs that already ran and change the values or change default values in job configurations?

Comment: Do you want to change the parameters of other jobs from this jenkins job??? If yes, why do you need to change the other job params from this job??

Or else build parameters you are talking about????

Comment: Using Jenkins' Script Console, I'd like to routinely change parameter values on some of my Jenkins jobs. I have several projects that start with the name "NAME" and each one of them has a String parameter ("B"). I need to change the value of "B" routinely and instead of doing so manually, I'd like to run a script from the Jenkins Script Console to do so. I managed to get every job that starts with "NAME" (as mentioned above) but I don't know how to access its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For jenkins 2.x try this

import hudson.model.*
def p1 = System.getenv("parameter1")